# Configure Jabber external component to send stanza on behalf of any user

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I read somewhere a while ago that one can configure external jabber components (XEP-0114) to send XMPP stanza's on behalf on any user. For instance say i have a component bind to (component.localhost) and i want it to send a message stanza with "from" attribute set to "user@localhost".

I am trying to achieve this with ejabberd. Won't be surprised if I will have to hack down ejabberd src to get this working (if at all possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using ejabberd, you can use the `{service_check_from, false}` option in your service definition to disable the verification on the "from" attribute.

Keep in mind, though, that [XEP 0114](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html) requires that the "host" part of the JIDs match the name of the component.

See the [corresponding section of ejabberd documentation](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc23) for all the gory details.

Comment: Hi Davux, Seems like you saved me from completing my server component i was working upon, now i can have the same thing in my external components.... this is exactly what i was looking for (though i haven't yet tested but looks promising).... Thankx

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you have to actually write the component, but this can easily be done.
You have first to confugre ejabberd so that it accepts connections on a specific for your component, with a given componet JID and a password. The default configuration file has several examples, for gateways for example.

Once this is done, connect an XMPP library/client with this component's credential and you should be good to go! The only constraint is that you send valid XML.

Comment: Hi Julien... I already have several components running (bind to component.localhost) and i am able to successfully send xmpp stanza's with "from" attribute set to "user@component.localhost". But i m looking for configuration steps (preferably with ejabberd) which can allow my component to send message on behalf of "user@localhost". Currently when my component tries to do so, they receive a 400 (Bad Request) error from the jabber server.

Answer (score 0):

Your component will typically only be allowed to send stanzas appearing to be from *@component.domain.com, rather than *@*.domain.com. This is a security feature.

If you want this functionality, you may have to write a server plugin rather than an external component.